# R - how to use `structural.em()` (from package `bnlearn`) to implement hidden variable learning in simple Bayesian network

Tags: bayesian-network

I want to use the function `structural.em()` to infer a hidden variable. As an example, consider the following code.

```
library(bnlearn)
n <- 500
A <- rnorm(n, 0, 1)
B <- 5 + 2*A + rnorm(n,0,1) 
C <- 10 + -2*B + rnorm(n,1) 

mydata1 <- data.frame(A,B,C)
head(mydata1)
```

Result:

```
           A        B            C
1  0.3671696 5.815983  1.219824527
2  1.5497029 7.367819 -4.746303052
3 -0.6208338 4.866273 -0.001548993
4  0.2813009 4.920910  1.060921207
5 -0.2560889 4.665860  0.241103140
6 -0.7785561 2.378321  8.488789586
```

Mathematically, we have 
$$\begin{align*} 
A &\sim N(0,1)\\
B|A=a &\sim N(5+2a,1)\\
C|B=b &\sim N(10-2b,1)\\
\end{align*}
$$

I am able to learn the structure:

```
learned <- hc(mydata1)
learned
```

Result

```
Bayesian network learned via Score-based methods

  model:
   [A][B|A][C|B] 
  nodes:                                 3 
  arcs:                                  2 
    undirected arcs:                     0 
    directed arcs:                       2 
  average markov blanket size:           1.33 
  average neighbourhood size:            1.33 
  average branching factor:              0.67 

  learning algorithm:                    Hill-Climbing 
  score:                                 BIC (Gauss.) 
  penalization coefficient:              3.107304 
  tests used in the learning procedure:  7 
  optimized:                             TRUE
```

And then train the network

```
dag.bnlearn.1 <- model2network("[A][B|A][C|B]")
est.para.1 <- bn.fit(dag.bnlearn.1, data = mydata1)
est.para.1
```

Result

```
Bayesian network parameters

  Parameters of node A (Gaussian distribution)

Conditional density: A
Coefficients:
(Intercept)  
-0.04004687  
Standard deviation of the residuals: 1.076409 

  Parameters of node B (Gaussian distribution)

Conditional density: B | A
Coefficients:
(Intercept)            A  
   4.992321     1.883480  
Standard deviation of the residuals: 0.9608345 

  Parameters of node C (Gaussian distribution)

Conditional density: C | B
Coefficients:
(Intercept)            B  
  10.917354    -1.974601  
Standard deviation of the residuals: 1.026824
```

which accurately learns the parameters for the network.

I cannot find an example of using `structural.em()` on hidden varaibles. I successfully implemented an example with missing data by doing

```
mydata2 <- mydata1
prop_miss <- 0.9
miss_idx <- sample(1:n, round(prop_miss*n), replace=FALSE)
mydata2[miss_idx,"A"] <- NA

my_sem <- structural.em(mydata2)
my_sem
```

Result

```
Bayesian network learned from Missing Data

  model:
   [A][B|A][C|B] 
  nodes:                                 3 
  arcs:                                  2 
    undirected arcs:                     0 
    directed arcs:                       2 
  average markov blanket size:           1.33 
  average neighbourhood size:            1.33 
  average branching factor:              0.67 

  learning algorithm:                    Structural EM 
  score-based method:                    Hill-Climbing 
  parameter learning method:             Maximum Likelihood 
  imputation method:                     
                   Posterior Expectation (Likelihood Weighting) 
  penalization coefficient:              3.107304 
  tests used in the learning procedure:  31 
  optimized:                             TRUE
```

Notice, how this example works as well.

But if I try, all missing, then I get an error

```
mydata3 <- mydata1
prop_miss <- 1
miss_idx <- sample(1:n, round(prop_miss*n), replace=FALSE)
mydata3[miss_idx,"A"] <- NA

my_sem <- structural.em(mydata3)
```

Result

```
Error in check.data(x, allow.levels = TRUE, allow.missing = TRUE, warn.if.no.missing = TRUE,  : 
  at least one variable has no observed values.
```

I checked the documentation using `help("structural.em",package="bnlearn")`. The documentation says

> If at least one of the variables in the data `x` does not contain any observed value, the `start` network must be specified and it must be a `bn.fit` object. Otherwise, `structural.em()` is unable to complete the first maximization step because it cannot fit the corresponding local distribution(s).

But if I try to fit a `bn.fit` object and then input it in the `start` argument, I get the following error

```
dag.bnlearn.2 <- model2network("[A][B|A][C|B]")
est.para.2 <- bn.fit(dag.bnlearn.2, data = mydata3)

structural.em(mydata3, start=est.para)
```

Result

```
Error in distribution(fitted = fitted, nodes = event, evidence = evidence, : 
all weights are NA, the probability of the evidence is impossible to compute.
```

Where am I going wrong? Can someone show me how to implement this toy example so that I can use the hidden learning feature of `structural.em()` properly to infer A from the data of B and C?